# native crash points to deleted libcrashreport.so

Tags: android, apptimize

Sometimes I come across crash reports that look quite similar to this one: http://en.miui.com/thread-663538-1-1.html.

In particular, note this:

```
backtrace:
    #00 pc 00000408  /data/data/com.XXXX.YYY/files/libcrashreport.so (deleted) (offset 0x7000)
    #01 pc 00091add  /system/lib/libart.so (offset 0x1cf000)
```

It seems to happen on some Android 7 builds. The specific offset in **libart.so** may be different, so is the offset in **libcrashreport.so**. But I could not find any mention of libcrashreport in the Android sources. And what would **`(deleted)`** mean? The APK does not ship with such library.

**PS**: Could this library be part of Apptimize SDK?

Comment: Did you fix this problem? I facing same issue. I do have Apptimize also

Comment: We have been working with Apptimize on this issue. They seem to have patched their library to avoid the crashes that we reported. Try to contact the company directly.